# File locking in R via flock package does not seem to work

Tags: r, file-locking, flock

I am running R 3.5.3 under Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with an ext4 file system on AWS.

I cannot seem to get file locking to work as it seems to me it should work.  Here is a reprex:

```
library(flock)

l1 <- lock("temp.txt", exclusive = TRUE)

# I expect this to fail but it doesn't
l2 <- lock("temp.txt", exclusive = TRUE)

# expect TRUE. Ok!
is.locked(l1)

# expect FALSE, but is TRUE
is.locked(l2)

unlock(l1)
# expect FALSE but is TRUE
is.locked(l1)

unlock(l2)
# expect FALSE but is TRUE
is.locked(l2)
```

So is flock broken, unsupported on this file system, or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its intended for locking processes in a "cluster" using the `parallel` package. For example:

```
mclapply(1:10, 
  function(v){
   l1 = lock("lock.txt")
   v*2
   Sys.sleep(1) 
   unlock(l1)
   return(v*2)},
  mc.cores=8)
```

will take about 10 seconds to run because each iteration has to wait until it can get the file lock, and its locked during the 1 second sleep, and the other process are waiting. If instead I do:

```
mclapply(1:10, 
  function(v){
   l1 = lock("lock.txt")
   v*2
   unlock(l1)
   Sys.sleep(1) 
   return(v*2)},
  mc.cores=8)
```

where the lock is *before* the sleep, then it runs in about 1 second since most of the time the processes are free to proceed.

So, use `lock` inside `parallel` executed parts to enable exclusive access to a shared resource. I'm not sure it makes much sense inside a single thread of R code. A single thread will always be able to get a lock on a file. The semantics are "is.locked.by.this.process" which is why you get TRUE the second time. Not sure that explains the behaviour of `is.locked` though, but I'm not sure testing if something is locked is good practice anyway - either get the lock and proceed, or unlock a held lock...

Comment: Note: `is.locked`  does __not__ test if the file is actually locked, it only looks into the object you pass, not at the file, and that object will always return `TRUE` no matter what. Analogously, `unlock` cannot actually unlock a file in general, it can only unlock the descriptor you created with `lock` and it will unlock all locks on the file not just the one you pass. So those are all just bugs in the package (and it uses obsolete record-level POSIX locks via `fcntl` which are considered really bad design and were superseded by the `flock` interface which is more reliable).